# Correct the view exhibition on android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a simple listview but I am receiving a wrong information and not a correct data form db.

```
List<Category> values = cdao.listAllItems();
ArrayAdapter<Category> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this,
   R.layout.row, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);


public List<Category> listAllItems() {
    List<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, category " +
            " FROM category", null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Category c = new Category();
        c.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        c.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category")));
        list.add(c);
        Log.d(wallet.utils.Constants.TAG, c.getCategory());
    }
    return list;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

The result of this is: wallet.entity.Category@44dbe038 and the correct value must be the word "General".

What is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was wrong. I forgot to override toString on my class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return category;
}
```

I hop that it can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(cursor.getCount > 0) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++) {
       Category c = new Category();
       c.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
       c.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category")));
       list.add(c);
       Log.d(wallet.utils.Constants.TAG, c.getCategory());
   }
}
```